# Refresh page with data from $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to send data to a index page when a link on that page is clicked. the index.php page looks like this:

```
include "../app/bootstrap.php";
include ("../src/controllers/DisplayContentsController.php");

$data = new DisplayContentsController();
$link = (isset($_POST['link']) ? $_POST['link'] : null);

if ($link != null)
{
    $data->show($twig, $starting_file_path . '/' . $link);
    $starting_file_path = $starting_file_path . '/' . $link;
}
else
{
    $data->show($twig, $starting_file_path);
}
```

and on the Twig template that is loaded I have this:

```
<script>
    jQuery('.show_content').click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();

        var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery.post(window.location, { link: href });
    });
</script>
```

I want to reload the page with the new link that way it loads the correct directory. But when I do the `jQuery.post()` the content that is displayed does not change. Can someone help my find out what is going wrong and how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Just to add something, but requests for content should be managed by GET and changes that should not be done twice managed by POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output from the POST request would be returned on the success handler function. For example, you would need to do something like this:

```
jQuery('.show_content').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery.post(window.location, { link: href } , function(data){
       //data will have the new HTML after the page posted back. You can use that
       //HTML to load if onto an element on the page. Something like:
       $('#content_result').html(data);           
    });
});
```

Assuming you have a `div` with "id = content_result" -or something like that- that you can use to load the HTML into it.

If you want to append the result to the existing HTML already displayed inside `#content_result` then simply do:

```
 $('#content_result').html($('#content_result').html()+data);
```

Now, keep in mind that this will return everything - the full page - and if you blindly keep appending things, you'll end up with a page that does not conform to valid HTML -for example, a page with more than 1 `<head>`,`<body>` sections, etc. The best thing to do is to extract the section that you really care about, and append only that section such that you always end up with a valid HTML document.

jQuery offers plenty of options to do this sort of thing.

Comment: that worked. Is there any way to append the results from that to the page so the old data stays? so the old directory contents stays and the new data that is made is just added to the page?

Comment: You mean something like $('#content_result').append(data)?
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Comment: @zachstarnes, totally, you can append the result if that's what you want. See my update.